# How do I migrate my data from one structure to another?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB with 3 collections. Here are the 3 collections each with an example of a document it contains:

`tag`

```
_id: ObjectId('61b873ec6d075801f7a97e18')
name: 'TestTag'
category: 'A'
```

---

`computer`

```
_id: ObjectId('6098c5ab615d9e23543d0f6f')
name: 'TestComputer'
category: 'A',
tags: [
    ObjectId('61b873ec6d075801f7a97e18')
]
```

---

`setting`

```
_id: ObjectId('61e56339b528bf009feca149')
name: 'TestSetting'
category: 'A',
tags: [
    ObjectId('61b873ec6d075801f7a97e18')
]
```

As you can see all 3 documents have a `category` property and the last 2 documents have a `tags` property. The idea is that you can create a tag and tag your computers and settings with the tag, but only within the same category.

Now I'm trying to go from `tags` to `groups`, so instead of tagging computers and settings, I have created a new group collection that looks like this:

`groups`

```
_id: ObjectId('63d2929c2c71e51f8ffcc921')
name: 'TestGroup'
category: 'A'
computers: []
settings: []
```

I want to "migrate" from ***tags*** to ***groups***. So for each tag in my tags collection, I want to create a group with the same name and same category. For each computer and setting that is tagged with that tag, I want to add their _id to the computers and settings arrays in the group.

So if we take the documents I've shown, it would create the following group:

```
_id: ObjectId('63d26d582c71e51f8ffcc8aa')
name: 'TestTag'
category: 'A'
computers: [
    ObjectId('6098c5ab615d9e23543d0f6f')
]
settings: [
    ObjectId('61e56339b528bf009feca149')
]
```

How do I make a query that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First perform `$group` to group all `tags` by category and name. Then, `$lookup` to `computer` and `setting` to find matching records. Finally, wrangle the `$lookup` results a bit and `$merge`/`$out` to `groups` collection.

```js
db.tag.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name",
        category: "$category"
      },
      tags: {
        "$addToSet": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "computer",
      "localField": "tags",
      "foreignField": "tags",
      "let": {
        c: "$_id.category"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$c",
                "$category"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "computers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "setting",
      "localField": "tags",
      "foreignField": "tags",
      "let": {
        c: "$_id.category"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$c",
                "$category"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "settings"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id.name",
      category: "$_id.category",
      computers: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$computers",
          "as": "c",
          "in": "$$c._id"
        }
      },
      settings: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$settings",
          "as": "s",
          "in": "$$s._id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "groups",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zekD_l_134b)